# How to get the path to the file using backslash symbol and 2 dots ('\..')

Tags: file, delphi, filepath

In Delphi program I use ExtractFileDir function for getting parent folder and this code works correctly:

```
Fmain.frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))))+'\FastReports\report1.fr3');
```

How can I modify it and get parent folder's path **with using "\.."** as it is realised in Delphi sample program

[image]

**Update:**

I wrote this code:

```
setcurrentdir('../../');
 s1:=getcurrentdir();
 frxReport1.LoadFromFile(s1+'\FastReports\report1.fr3');
```

but I want one-line(as my code with ExtractFileDir ) and well-readable code to replace my code.

Comment: I'd first expand the filename to an absolute path using watever directory the path is relative too, and then your existing code will work fine. So I think your question is, "how to I expand a file name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a function which absolutize a relative path.
To absolutize a path, you need to know the base path.

I the case of Delphi you show, the paths are relative to the project directory.

Once you have an absolute path, you can apply ExtractFilePath several times to go up in the directory levels.

Let's take an example: You have a relative path "....\SomeFile.txt". This path is relative to the base path "C:\ProgramData\Acme\Project\Demo". The complete path is: "C:\ProgramData\Acme\Project\Demo....\SomeFile.txt". Then the absolute path result of AbsolutizePath will be "C:\ProgramData\Acme\SomeFile.txt".

Note that Absolutize path take care of ".." (parent directory), "." (Current directory) and drive specification (Such as C:).

```
function AbsolutizePath(
    const RelPath  : String;
    const BasePath : String = '') : String;
var
    I, J : Integer;
begin
    if RelPath = '' then
        Result := BasePath
    else if RelPath[1] <> '\' then begin
        if (BasePath = '') or
           ((Length(RelPath) > 1) and (RelPath[2] = ':')) then
            Result := RelPath
        else
            Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(BasePath) + RelPath;
    end
    else
        Result := RelPath;
    // If there is no drive in the result, add the one from base if any
    if (Length(Result) > 1) and (Result[2] <> ':') and
       (Length(BasePath) > 1) and (BasePath[2] = ':') then
        Insert(Copy(BasePath, 1, 2), Result, 1);
    // Delete "current dir" marker
    I := 1;
    while TRUE do begin
        I := Pos('\.\', Result, I);
        if I <= 0 then
            break;
        Delete(Result, I, 2);
    end;
    // Process "up one level" marker
    I := 1;
    while TRUE do begin
        I := Pos('\..\', Result, I);
        if I <= 0 then
            break;
        J := I - 1;
        while (J > 0) and (not CharInSet(Result[J], ['\', ':'])) do
            Dec(J);
        // Check if we hit drive delimiter and fix it
        if (J = 2) and (Result[J] = ':') then
            J := 3;
        Delete(Result, J + 1, I - J + 3);
        I := J;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Or simply `SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH); PathCanonicalize(PChar(Result), PChar(TPath.Combine(BasePath, RelPath)); Result := PChar(Result);`

Comment: Exactly @Branko. On Windows you call the system API to do the job.

Comment: fpiette, I would like not to write my own so big function but to use '\ ..'  in native Delphi functions like setcurrentdir, Getcurrentdir, ExtractfileDir, ExtractfilePath etc. As is shown  in above delphi sampe code using '\..'  is more readable then the use 3 times of Extractfiledir.   
Does it exist way to write one-line code like my code but to use '\..' in it?

Comment: @basti That is not what I call a "big" function. Actually, it is rather small, simple and portable. But you are free to use whatever you like :-)

Comment: @fpiette I appreciate your work. This is very nice and useful function (I will store it for future) but at that moment I would like only one-line code like my code but with '\..' in it. I thought it was possible. Please see update

Comment: @basti Use my function. Once you put it in a source file, you can forget it has a few lines. Calling it will be only one line. Pass it BasePath the value of current directory. Not that you are probably confusing the current directory when your program is run and the directory where you program is stored. This is frequently the same, but not always!

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 10

```
using
...
System.IOUtils
...

lAppPath := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
lPathOffset := '.\..\..\..\..\.tmp\';
FTmpFolder :=  TPath.GetFullPath(TPath.Combine(lAppPath, lPathOffset));
```